# Photocopying using a separate scanner and printer

Tags: windows-7, printer, printing, scanning

I have 2 printers.

1. HP Deskjet F2235 - designated **scanner** (has printing issues)
2. Brother HL-2040 - designated **printer** (doesn't have a scanner)

Just by using those two both connected to the same computer, is there a way to perform a photocopy operation by scanning via the designated scanner then immediately it being printed from the designated printer?

Obviously you could save the scanned files then print them, but short of making a script or manually doing this, is there a faster automatic way through settings or third-party software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something commonly referred to as "photocopier software".

See e.g. http://www.filesland.com/companies/NEOGIE-Software/SimpleCopier.html

Or http://www.lucersoft.com/lccopier/lccopinfo.php (Shareware, 19$).

or http://www.nicocuppen.com/pit/editor/page_detail.php?id=10103 (free to download)

Caveat: I have not tried any of these.

Comment: lol "photocopier software", who would have guessed right? thanks for the links, shall do some field testing

Comment: the software on the last link worked just fine, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [iCopy Free Photocopier](http://icopy.sourceforge.net/):

> iCopy Free Photocopier is a freeware
>   and open source application that lets
>   you combine your scanner and printer
>   into a powerful, but easy to use
>   photocopier by only pressing a button.
>
> You can run iCopy by just pressing the
>   button of your scanner!!
>
> Its simple user interface lets you
>   manage scanner and printer options,
>   like brightness, contrast, number of
>   copies in a couple of seconds.
>
> As it’s small and no installation is
>   required, iCopy is also suitable for
>   USB pen drives.
>
> iCopy is distributed under the GNU
>   General Public License 3 (GNU GPL v3).

[image]

Comment: iCopy is pretty good, but for some reason it keeps giving me errors on my machine as well as issues with brightness on the photocopy. I still like the fact it's open source so I can modify it myself. Thanks